# Add Data To An Object Without Overiding It

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

so I have an object, and I want to add some information inside it. The issue is, is that the information that is being added, is inside a for loop. So the current information in the object gets overridden. Is there a way I can just do object.add(key, value), so the current information inside the object does not get overridden? Thanks!

```js
const GetCommandFromFile = require( `../commands/${dirsin[i]}/${allfiles[i][ii]}` );
//^ this keeps changing, as this entire code is inside a for loop

const key = GetCommandFromFile.commands[0];
const value = GetCommandFromFile;
const objectToSet = new Object();

objectToSet[key] = value1;
//^ this keeps overriding the previous data inside the object. How to fix?

await map.set( dirsin[i],  objectToSet );
log.info(map)
```

Map Result: https://sourceb.in/LGwvoIDRXY
Take Example From The 'Dev' Value, Inside The Object, There Is Only 1 Entry, When There Should Be 4, However The Object Keeps Getting Overridden.

Comment: Do you want an `Object` (hash) or an `Array` (list)?  Both would allow you to story collections of data, but the first is key/property-based and the second is ordered/index-based.

Comment: With the work I am doing, an object would be much easier, although I get that an array would also work (along with a map)

Comment: I kind of just want to know if its possible. If it is possible, then I would do it, if not I would use an array or map.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still trying to understand your requirement-- if you were packing multiple values into this container, how would you wish to retrieve them?

Comment: So I have a separate program that needs the data to be organized, it would be easier if I could just use the map, do map.get('foldername') then .filename, its just a mater of convenience. The whole entire file is like 800 lines so I just cut it down to this much.

Comment: So I'm still a bit confused as to the details, but I'm thinking an array sounds like the best option here; if you rewrote your problem line as `objectToSet[key] = !objectToSet[key] ? [value1] : objectToSet[key].push(value1);` it would make it an array when it was `undefined` and otherwise just push to the array.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! Yeah I tried for a bit, it made no sense. Appreciate the help :D